# Difference in the meanings of the words and when to use which one?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am a regular Asphalt gamer. There are various levels which unlocks by playing the previous levels under the same category. The manner of unlock and labels are:

- Novice
- Rookie
- Pro
- Elite
- Master

All of a sudden by interest piqued and I searched up the meanings of these words and started comparing them. It is not that I never knew, just it didn't occur to me to find out more. So I searched up the meanings of these words such as **novice, rookie, neophyte, amateur.** All of them appeared to be the exact same to me (I am talking in respects to their knowledge of a work or sport). Although each of them had similar meanings in religious contexts too.

So now my question is, when to use which word in a sentence? Like if I am introducing my colleague who is the newest addition in the team, which word is the most suitable of all? (formal and informal usage both will be appreciated)

The meanings I referred to:
[Novice](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/novice), [Rookie](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rookie), [Neophyte](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/neophyte), [Amateur](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/amateur)

Comment: An individual game can decide to call its difficulty levels or player levels. Within one specific game, *novice* and *rookie* are different. Outside the game, the semantics are fuzzier, and you're ultimately asking a workplace etiquette question. I would **not** introduce a new colleague with any of these terms. For instance, "amateur" suggests that the worker is not a professional. Instead, I'd say something like, "Here is the newest addition to our team!" or "Here is our new [job title], [name]!"

Comment: The first three mean a person who is new to an activity or job, but _amateur_ means someone who engages in an activity literally 'for love' and doesn't get paid for doing it. An amateur artist, musician or sportsman _could_ be highly skilled, though most are not.

Comment: @KateBunting In crime fiction the _amateur sleuth_ is, of course, often better at it than the professional. Most famously Miss Marple and Lord Peter Wimsey.

Comment: Often, the only way to know when a reasonable-looking candidate is appropriate in a certain context is by familiarity. Though collocation dictionaries can help. Here, the ad-hoc ranking of 'novice' below 'rookie' probably fits with standard usage, but the rest seem arbitrarily arranged.